# Getting all ancestors of an element from a table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am building a badges app in CodeIgniter using a MySQL database. There are 3 types of badges: level 1, level 2 and level 3 badges.

Each level 2 badge is awarded once you get all the required level 1 badges and each level 3 badge is awarded once you get all the required level 1 and level 2 badges. There is also a level 3 badge that requires getting 4 level 3 badges.

I have the following database table for my badges relations:

```
badge_id - children_id
    1    -     20
    1    -     25
    20   -     40
    20   -     45
    26   -     40
    25   -     39
    40   -     50
```

I need a function that returns me all the ancestors of a badge.
For example, if the function recieved the argument 50 it would return: 40, 26, 20, 1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to handle it by pure mysql, you need to declare a mysql stored procedure which has some depth limitations.

Instead of that I would recommend using a simple recursive PHP function to return what you need:

```
function get_ancestors($child_id, $badges)
{
    $found = array();
    foreach($badges as $k => $row){
        if ($row['children_id'] == $child_id){
            $found = array_merge($found, get_ancestors($row['badge_id'], $badges));
            $found[] = $row['badge_id'];
        }
    }
    return $found;
}
```

The $badges variable holds all the rows from your badges relations table, just simply read it out from the database.

Based on the example you gave, for the following call

```
get_ancestors(50, $badges);
```

the output would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 20
    [2] => 26
    [3] => 40
)
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfectly for me. I haven't thought of this approach.